# Pine Script - Conditional plot based on horizontal line

Tags: pine-script

Just wondering if anyone knows if it's possible to plot a shape only IF it passes through a horizontal line.

For example, if I want to say something is a hanging man only IF it meets the normal hanging man criteria AND the candle has passed through a horizontal line I've plotted.

e.g. on the image below the left hand one didn't touch the purple horizontal line so I don't want that to be labelled a hanging man. The candle on the right however did interact with the line, so should show (as it is) as a hanging man.

Any help kindly appreciated.

Thank you!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would just need to add this to your hanging man condition

```
high >= purple_line and low <= purple_line
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, this wouldn't quite do what I'm after I'm afraid. I'd need to see if any price during the candle crossed one of the horizontal lines if that makes sense? any ideas please? thanks again

Comment: Then you'll need to provide more details or be clearer otherwise it's impossible to know what you're really asking.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. So what you've provided is saying if the high or low value of the candle is greater/less then a horizonal line...that only compares two values (the high and low) of the candle against the position of the horizontal line...and not all values of the candle between open and close. If a candle fluctuated between 95 (low) and 100 (high), I'd want the logic to check if 95, 96, 97, 98, 99 or 100 interacted with the horizontal line. Hopefully that helps clarify a bit?

Comment: I've added another screenshot to the initial post which hopefully helps clarify too - thanks again for your help with this.

Comment: Let's say the purple line is 97. If the candle's high is 100 and the low is 95, then we know that the purple line was crossed at least once during that bar. Do you just mean the candle body? If you want to check the candle body you would use `max(open,close)` and `min(open,close)` instead of high and low. You just need to combine the conditions eg. `validHang = hangingManCondition and high >= purple and low <= purple`